# jQuery and form validation in a C# MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index.cshtml in a C# application.  This is the code of the form:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CheckPlanID", "ForgotUserID", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    <section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #508bfc;">
       <div class="container py-5 h-100">

          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
                <div class="card shadow-2-strong" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
                    <div class="card-body p-5 text-center">

                        <h3 class="mb-5">Forgot User ID</h3>

                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <label id="errorLabel" name="errorLabel" class="form-label @Model.GeneralErrorColor">@Model.GeneralError</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                            <input type="text" id="PlanID" asp-for="PlanID" name="PlanID" class="form-control form-control-lg" value="@Model.PlanID" />
                            <label class="form-label @Model.ErrorPlanIDColor" for="PlanID">@Model.ErrorPlanID</label>
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" id="nextButton" onclick="DisplayProgressMessage(this, 'Login');">Next</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </section>

   <div class="submit-progress hidden" style="background-color: #3b5998; text-align: center;">
      <i class="fa fa-2x fa-refresh fa-spin" style="color: white"></i>
      <label style="color: white">Please wait...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
   </div>
 }
```

When the user clicks on the Next button, I execute the following jQuery:

```
 <script>
      function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {

      var planID = $("#PlanID").val();
      console.log("plan ID = " + planID);
      console.log("length = " + planID.length);
      if (planID.length == 4) {
         $(ctl).prop("disabled", true).text(msg);
         $("#nextButton").prop("disabled", true);
         // Wrap in setTimeout so the UI
         // can update the spinners
         setTimeout(function () {
             $(".submit-progress").removeClass("hidden");
         }, 1);
         $("form").submit()
     }

     $("#errorLabel").text = "The Plan ID must be 4 characters in length";

 }
 </script>
```

When I run the application and type in 4 characters into the input box and click on the Next button, the jQuery executes, the hidden  gets displayed, and the form gets submitted to my controller.  This is correct.

When I run the application and type in 2 characters into the input box and click on the Next button, the jQuery executes, the hidden <div< does not get displayed, but the form still gets submitted to my controller.

How can I get jQuery to not submit the form when the length of the data typed into the input box is not 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since your button has a type of "submit" it will always submit the parent form, unless you prevented the events default behavior.

The easiest solution is to change your button to type = "button".

Comment: gotta love easy.  Thank you very much!